# H.264 stream in WPF GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, directshow

I am developing a Window7, C#/WPF based GUI and I want to show H.264 video which I get from the RTP stream of a video call. I am using a C based open source library for making the video call. This is what I want to implement: The user dials a URI by typing in the address and pressing the call button and when the video call is established the H.264 stream is seen in the WPF GUI window.

Does the latest WPF support H.264? If not, what other windows based framework/technology can I use to show H.264 video on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WPF VideoElement can show H264, if you have latest windows media player installed(I think windows7 has WMP installed by default).
If that doesn't benefit you, you can always use MediaKit that can do everything: http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/ (you can feed your own DirectShow graph to VideoElement by registering new protocol - basically means anything is possible this way)

Comment: Thanks. I am a WPF/DS newbie. Is there sample code available to show me how to register a new protocol to feed DS graph in unmanaged code to WpfMediaKit Video Element?